# Give Kendo UI PanelBar li element an id from dataSource

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource, panelbar

I want to bind an id from my datasource to each li element for a PanelBar so I can use this id later to expand a given node. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I havent worked with panelbar but this is coming from a grid. You can get access to values off the Model by using `'#=Name #'`. It seems that it needs '' if it is calling a JS function

```
columns.Bound(m => m.OwnerName).Title("Owner Name")
.ClientTemplate("<a href='javascript: void(0);' onclick=\"return 
openMSDynamicsWindow('#= OwnerUrl #');\">#= OwnerName #</a>");
```

Here's the Javascript that was generated, not sure how it would work. I don't understand why those numbers are added into places

```
{"columns":[{"title":"Subsys #",
"template":"\u003ca href=\u0027javascript: void(0);\u0027 onclick=\"return   str(\u0027mystring\u0027);\"\u003e#= Name #\u003c/a\u003e",

"field":"Subsys","filterable":{},"encoded":true},
```

Comment: I just use the opensource version and not the commercial wrapper, can you please tell me how this is translated into JS ?

Comment: I posted the JS that renders above, not sure what you would need to code